# What is the Bootstrap 4.0+ equivalent to ".hidden-size-down/up"

Tags: bootstrap-4, hidden, display

```
<div class="justify-content-center">
  <p class="hidden-md-down"> TEXT </p>
</div>
```

BootStrap used to be able to 'hide' a element on resizing using '.hidden'.

It looks like this no longer works.

What is the 4.0+ equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 has the .d-none class. ([official documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/#hiding-elements))

To hide an element on screens smaller than 960px you could use the class's `d-none` 
& `d-lg-block`

```
<div class="d-none d-lg-block">hide on screens smaller than lg</div>
```